# How to omit data from an array return

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula, average

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(ABS(L52:M100)))
```

Some of the data is 0 so it is affecting the calculation. How do I omit the 0 data?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you meant `=AVERAGEIF(L52:M100; "<>0")` ? .. plus I added the google sheets tag (did I suppose correctly?)

Comment: Yes google sheets :)